# Приведение записи из выборки к пользовательскому типу и обращение к столбцу

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно привести `record` из `select` к пользовательскому типу.

Создан тип:

```
create or replace type test_rec is object (
   name varchar2(10),
   id number
)
```

Сам запрос:

```
select *
  from (SELECT test_rec(ID, NAME)
          FROM (select '1' as id, 'Вася' as name
                  from dual
                union all
                select '2' as id, 'Маша' as name
                  from dual))
  where id = 2
```

Возникает ошибка:

> ora-00904 "ID" invalid identifier.

Без условия  `where id = 2` все работает. Можно ли как-то обратится к столбцу после приведения к типу? Желательно без алиасов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы селектитке объектный тип, поэтому id у него - поле, а не столбец. Не очень понятно желание "без алиасов", но рабочий вариант выглядит так -

```
select *
  from (SELECT test_rec(NAME, ID) as val
          FROM (select 'Вася' as name, 1 as id
                  from dual
                union all
                select 'Маша' as name, 2 as id
                  from dual)) s
  where s.val.id = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

> Можно ли как-то обратится к столбцу после приведения к типу? Желательно без алиасов.

Можно конечно, но в вопросе обращение к аттрибуту столбца, и тут без алиаса нельзя, о чём прямо сказано в кап. [2.1.8.1 When Table Aliases Are Required](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adobj/Sql-object-types-and-references.html#GUID-70591B87-FEAC-4C63-9866-B86231705B44).

> You must qualify a reference to an object attribute or subprogram with a table alias rather than a table name even if the table name is itself qualified by a schema name.

Кроме того, порядок аргументов в конструкторе пользовательского типа нарушен.

Надо так: первое условие - по столбцу, второе - по аттрибуту столбца:

```
with data as (
    select test_rec ('Вася', 1) as rec from dual union all
    --select test_rec (66, 'Ой')       from dual union all --ORA-01722: invalid number 
    select test_rec ('Маша', 2)        from dual
)
select *  
from data d  
where rec      = test_rec ('Маша', 2)
and   d.rec.id = 2 
;

REC                                                                            
----------------------------
SH.TEST_REC(Маша, 2)
```

Заметьте, обращение к столбцу без алиаса.